# What Request OAuth2 parameters used for accessing Public RESTServer app on Azure

Tags: azure, rest, delphi, request, crud

I am trying to get my RESTClient's CRUD Requests to work after retrieving the access-token from Azure but I don't know what parameters need to be added and I cannot find examples of the syntax that work, or maybe my app's registration info isn't correct for a REST API.  Both apps are written Delphi 10.4.2 (Sydney).

I have a RESTServer/RESTClient pair of apps (originated using the IDE's DataSnap wizards).  I added a RESTful WebAction to the RESTServer and a corresponding GET Request to the RESTClient, and they perform perfectly if both apps reside on my network or both are on a drive in my Azure Windows Server VM.  I wish to have only the RESTServer app on Azure so I am trying to get my RESTClient app to connect to the RESTServer app on Azure Windows Server VM.

I put a TOAuth2Authenticator component on a form in my Delphi 10.4.2 app and was able to confirm that I can retrieve the Access-Token using the identity values from Azure app registration info.  The registration specifies that this is a "Public" API and I created a Scope for it but I'm not sure a Scope is needed for a Public REST API.

If I ping the Public IP of the VM I get "Request timed out." but I'm assuming that is normal and retrieval of the token works anyway, which is confirmed in the following code from this test app:

```
procedure TMainForm.RESTTokenRequestAfterExecute(Sender: TCustomRESTRequest);
begin
if RESTTokenResponse.StatusCode = 200 then
  begin
  MyAuthToken := RESTTokenResponse.JSONValue.GetValue<String>('access_token');
  OAuth2Authenticator5.AccessToken := FConnection.MyAuthToken; // store it here in case I decide to use this component.
```

That code and the RESTClient code to retrieve the token are based on this demo app:
https://github.com/jfbilodeau/AzureRESTExample

But the following code (and dozens of variations) in my app always times out with
ENetHTTPClientException with message 'Error sending data: (12002) The operation timed out'.
ERESTException with message 'REST request failed: Error sending data: (12002) The operation timed out'.

I've read messages that suggest that the Resource parameter is not used now, at least not for Public APIs, and I don't see any examples about how to specify the Scope in Delphi components.

Intuitively, it would make sense to apply a "REST Endpoint" URL to these Requests that use the Token for subsequent contact.

Is all of that handled by the contents of the Token?  I have parsed the Token at jwt.io and cannot tell if it contains all that is needed for the connection.  I could redact some of that and include it if that would be helpful.

```
procedure MyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
  RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
  strImageJSON : string;
begin
  RESTClient1 := TRESTClient.Create('http://<Azure Public IP>:8080/'); // tried https also
  try
    RESTRequest1 := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
    try
      RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET; // or rmPOST?
      // MyAzureResource from Delphi RESTServer app's WebModule.WebActionItem's Pathinfo
      RESTRequest1.Resource := 'api/<AzureClientID>/<MyAzureResource>'; 
      RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('MyKey1', 'MyValue1', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY);
      RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('MyKey2', 'MyValue2', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY);
      RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('Authorization','Bearer ' + FConnection.AuthToken);
      RESTRequest1.Client := RESTClient1;
      RESTRequest1.Execute;
      strImageJSON := RESTRequest1.Response.Content;
    finally
      RESTRequest1.Free;
    end;
  finally
    RESTClient1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When not connecting to Azure, the basic Request with only these 2 parameters works fine:

RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('MyKey1', 'MyValue1');
RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('MyKey2', 'MyValue2');

Can you tell me what is wrong with this Request under Azure?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of your call made with indy10 on delphi 11

```
    procedure TForm1.pippo;
    var
    fIdHTTP: TIdHTTP;  //unit IdHTTP
    fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL; //unit IdSSLOpenSSL
    responseCall, url: string;
    responseCodeCall: Integer;
    StringStream: TStringStream;
    data : TJSONObject; //unit System.Json
    begin


      //set the ssl versione
      fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
      with fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions do begin
        Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
        Mode   := sslmClient;
        SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
      end;

      //create the object that will do the call
      fIdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);

      //assign the ssl option to your idhttp object
      fIdHTTP.IOHandler := fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

      //set foldlines property of custom headers at false then with the add pair
      //add your bearer token
      fIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := false;
      fIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddPair('Authorization','Bearer ' + '<token>');

      //i like to set set the default responde of the call to error
      responseCall :=  '';
      responseCodeCall := 500;

      //Create the object that your passing
      data := TJSONObject.Create;
      data.AddPair('MyKey1', 'MyValue1');
      data.AddPair('MyKey2', 'MyValue2');
      // this code /\ it's equal to create a string like this \/ and then passit to the call instead of data.ToJson
      //    {
      //        "MyKey1": "MyValue1",
      //        "MyKey2": "MyValue2",
      //    }

      StringStream := nil;

      url := 'http://<Azure Public IP>:8080/api/<AzureClientID>/<MyAzureResource>';;

      try
        try

          //transform the body of your request (the json) into a stream
          StringStream := TStringStream.Create(data.ToJSON, TEncoding.UTF8);
          //By the fact that you're sending a body i assume it's not a get but a post
          //but better check the specification of the api
          //Make a post passing the stream of the body
          responseCall := fIdHTTP.Post(url,StringStream);

          //get the response of the call
          responseCodeCall := fIdHTTP.ResponseCode;

        except  //All error handle
          on e1: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
          begin
            responseCodeCall := fIdHTTP.ResponseCode;
            responseCall := e1.ErrorMessage;
          end;
          on E: Exception do
          begin
            responseCodeCall := 500;
            responseCall := e.Message;
          end;
        end;

      finally

        if StringStream <> nil then
          StringStream.Free;

        data.free;

        fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Free;
        fIdHTTP.Free;

      end;


      if (responseCodeCall >= 200) and (responseCodeCall <= 299) then
        //Great success
      else
        //Great unseccess :(

    end;
```

it should work fine on Sydney version

Comment: I will try that as-is because I already know that the client-server connection works fine when not needing to send the token when both are on Azure or both are on my network.  If it doesn't work, that would suggest that the problem is on the Azure app registration side so I can then concentrate on that.  I'll get back with you about that.  Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: I still get a time-out using your approach so this makes it seem that the problem is more likely related to the configuration of the App Registration information in our Azure Windows Server VM.

However, I am not 100% sure I know what value needs to be in your <MyAzureResource>.  I've been using the the "Client App ID" in the tests that time-out.

Do you know if using that as <MyAzureResouce> is correct?

Comment: If you have similar boilerplate code for using Indy on the Azure server side too, that would help me to eliminate some gap in my understanding of the DataSnap Server code that runs just find as a REST server when it's in the same location as the Client, whether on Azure or not.

Comment: no sorry i usually work withg cloudrun written in java on a gcp platform.
but just know, on your amazon control panel don't see any request coming?
just to know try to make both calls, mine and yours to this site https://requestcatcher.com/ it show you what you've sent, the pass both here to give a look(obviously put fake credential it always answer 200)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that too.  I am NOT on AWS.  The "app registration" settings I'm trying to make are on Microsoft Azure because the RESTServer app is on an Azure Windows Server VM.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing the authorization bearer token as parameter and not as an header try this code

```
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + FConnection.AuthToken);
```

> Sending Authorization Bearer Token Header. To send a request with the
> Bearer Token authorization header, you need to make an HTTP request
> and provide your Bearer Token in the "Authorization: Bearer {token}"
> HTTP header. A Bearer Token is a cryptic string typically generated by
> the server in response to a login request
>
> [https://reqbin.com/req/adf8b77i/authorization-bearer-header#:~:text=Sending%20Authorization%20Bearer%20Token%20Header,response%20to%20a%20login%20request](https://reqbin.com/req/adf8b77i/authorization-bearer-header#:%7E:text=Sending%20Authorization%20Bearer%20Token%20Header,response%20to%20a%20login%20request).

in your code you where sending the authorization as a request parameter

btw if i can give you a suggestion try to use indy to make rest call is pretty easy and you can handle everything IMO

Comment: I have also used the following syntax to put it in the header, to no avail.

Comment: RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('Authorization','Bearer ' +FConnection.AuthToken, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER

But I also want to make sure I am clear about a couple of additional things:

First, I have already gotten the Auth-Code/Token and exchanged it for the Access-Token which is what I am passing here despite is being called "AuthToken" because the Access-Token is said to "replace" the AuthToken in the examples was looking at.  

Is that Access-Token NOT what I should be passing?

Comment: I am looking at the Indy Client components and if you could say a little about which ones to use and a tiny bit about how to configure them, that would be helpful. 

As it is, since my Delphi RESTClient performs fine when not trying to reach the RESTServer on the Azure Windows Server VM, I'm trying to find which values in the Delphi Client component to plug in to which value in the corresponding IndyClient.